# How can I disable keybindings for languages I don't use in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I don't use PHP, but when I type `if` or `else` in Rails ERB templates and then hit `tab`, I'm given the option to insert PHP if/else statements.

How can I disable that?

I'd be fine with completely removing anything PHP-related as I don't use it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into the same small annoyance while working on django templates.

1. Navigate to: /path/to/sublime_text_3/Packages
2. Delete or move PHP.sublime-package
3. Restart Sublime Text

Edit:

Another (less permanent) option that should work is adding "PHP" to the list of "ignored_packages" in user settings:

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage", // Ignored in default settings
        "PHP"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For me, on OS X, the path was `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages`.